# Twitterizer2 1.2.4 Streaming API exception - Unexpected end when deserializing object

Tags: c#, json.net, twitterizer

Any help would be appreciated. I'm getting an exception thrown during deserialization inside JSON.Net:

Unexpected end when deserializing object. Line 216, position 2.

My calling code:
var asyncResult = s.StartPublicStream(streamErrorCallback, statusCreatedCallback, statusDeletedCallback, eventCallback, rawJsonCallback);

Setting a breakpoint in my rawJsonCallback handler shows (what appears to be) valid JSON coming back from the API.

Added the source for Twitterizer2 and JSON.Net, looks like Twitterizer.Streaming.TwitterStream.ParseMessage(string) is failing here near line 520

```
var user = obj.SelectToken("user", false);
    if (user != null)
        {
            if (statusCreatedCallback != null && user.HasValues)
            {
                statusCreatedCallback(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitterStatus>(ConvertJTokenToString(obj)));

            }
            return;
        }
```

On the call to DeserializeObject().

Newtonsoft.Json.Serliazation.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject() fails because the reader.TokenType == None.

I suspect there is a discrepancy between the contract type/values and the object coming back from the API, but I'm not sure how to test further. Wasn't able to get the Json.Net source to compile so I can't step through it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Twitterizer 2.4 is using NewtonSoft.Json v4.08, which breaks it. Install Newtonsoft.Json v4.03, and you'll be fine.

Comment: This is the double edge to the nuget sword.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your issue. I had a simillar one when I wanted to use the twitterize with JSON.NET 4.5

I follow the steps that someone mentioned on [github](https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer/pull/55/files) and then I've compiled the whole source code with the new json lib and voilá ;)